# Priority in chained comparisons in Julia, does "var1 && var2 != 1" mean "(var1 and var2) != 1"?

Tags: comparison-operators, chained, julia

I have a questions regarding the chained comparisons in Julia. I read [this section in the manual](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/mathematical-operations/) but it is still unclear.

In Julia, does this:

```
if var1 && var2 != 1
```

mean this (in Python):

```
if (var1 and var2) != 1:
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I could read on that page and a linked page (http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/control-flow/#man-short-circuit-evaluation), no. The order of operations is different. It ends up like this:

```
if (var1) && (var2 != 1)
```

First, the xscalar variable gets checked for a value that would satisfy an if statement, as if you did

```
if var1
```

Then, if, and only if that is accepted, does the next part get evaluated:

```
if var2 != 1
```

In other words, these two statements are roughly equivalent:

```
if var1
    if var2 != 1

and

if var1 && var2 != 1
```

(forgive the lack of julia syntax knowledge)

A python equivalent of this would be:

```
if var1 and var2 != 1:
```

or, with parentheses to show with more clarity,

```
if (var1) and (var2 != 1) :
```

Comment: you mean: `if (xscalar) and (dim != 1)` ?

Comment: I was trying to explain the order the values were evaluated, still in julia, not python

Comment: could you propose one equivalent in Python, or add some analogy to Python?

Comment: and you beat me to changing my answer too :P

Answer (score 13):

You can always quote an expression to see how the parser interprets it:

```
julia> :(var1 && var2 != 1)
:(var1 && (var2!=1))
```

In this case, the `!=` binds more tightly than the `&&`. This is standard precedence in languages that have these two operators) such as C and Java.

Comment: this quoting feature is very useful! Thank you!